# Which passive form is correct?

Tags: passive-voice

"I opened the door."

a)The door was opened.

b)The door was opened by me.

Are the two options correct? Is the agent required in this sentence?

Comment: Both are correct, the agent is not obligatory, you can put it if you want your listener to know *who* opened the door.

Comment: In a normal conversation (not in a police interrogation, for example), a native speaker, when asked who opened the door, is far more likely to say "*I* opened the door" (with vocal emphasis on the first-person pronoun) than "the  door was opened by me".  Many active-to-passive exercises give learners a very distorted sense of when the passive is to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @user178049, both sentences in the passive are correct.

In the passive voice, you can omit who the doer is.  But if you want to focus on the doer, you can add  by + the doer.